# How is the pseudo-inverse of $A \oplus A$ related to psueod-inverse of A

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a real $2n \times 2n$ diagonalizable real matrix. I can write $A$ as the product $A= UV$ where $U$ and $V$ are real symmetric matrices where $U$ is block diagonal with $I_{n \times n}$ as one of the blocks. $U$ has a zero eigenvalue so it has only pseudoinverse, and similarly for $A$. $V$ is invertible. From now on inverse will mean pseudo-inverse where necessary. The question is can I relate the pseudo-inverse of $A \oplus A = I \otimes A + A \otimes I$ to inverses of $U$ and $V$ (where $\otimes$ is Kronecker product). I know there is already a formula for the inverse through diagonalization of $A$ but I dont want to use that since for me inverse of $V$ is already given and inverting $U$ numerically is easy since it is symmetric and sparse.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful, but we can write
$$
A \oplus A = (A \otimes I)(A^{-1} \otimes A + I \otimes I)
$$
(I think this might just lead to another formula via diagonalization, unfortunately)

Comment: Well this could be somewhat helpful if $A^{-1} \otimes A$ had spectral radius less than $1$ but it has spectral radius 1 :p

Comment: I wasn't even thinking in terms of Von Neumann sums, interesting! But yes, that is also a dead end, it seems.